# Make sense to native speakers: 'I am hardly ever optimistic about my future' and 'I am hardly ever pessimistic about my future'

Tags: time-words

I wonder if the following sentences sound natural to native speakers of English:

'I am hardly ever optimistic about my future.' and
'I am hardly ever pessimistic about my future.'

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hello Chet and welcome to ELL! Unfortunately, asking if a sentence is good is a request for proof reading, which is off-topic on this site, so I'm closing your question. If you don't understand how to use the structure "hardly ever", then please edit your question to be about what you don't understand. Please also check out How to Ask a Good Question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They sound fine but, to my UK ears, *slightly* more formal than:

> "I hardly ever feel optimistic about the future."

I think we prefer "...**the** future" to "...**my** future". Unless we are discussing, say, climate change, we take it for granted that you are speaking about your own future.

There is a subtle difference between **being** optimistic and **feeling** optimistic. "I am hardly ever optimistic..." might suggest you *express* or *exhibit* this lack of optimism. As a child might say, "I was feeling angry but I didn't BE angry."